# Flask Dynamic data update without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

i'm trying to create something like Google Suggest Tool (via suggest api http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ru&q=query )

I'm listening input changes, and send data go GET:

```
$("#search_form_input").keyup(function(){
var some_var = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url: "",
      type: "get", //send it through get method
      data:{jsdata: some_var},
      success: function(response) {

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
    });
```

After that i'm handling this data and send it to Google API and got response in Python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start_page_data():
    query_for_suggest = request.args.get('jsdata')

    if query_for_suggest == None:
        suggestions_list = ['',]
        pass
    else:
        suggestions_list = []
        r = requests.get('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ru&q={}&gl=in'.format(query_for_suggest), 'lxml')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        suggestions = soup.find_all('suggestion')
        for suggestion in suggestions:
            suggestions_list.append(suggestion.attrs['data'])
        print(suggestions_list)
    return render_template('start_page.html', suggestions_list=suggestions_list)
```

In Jinja trying to print it in HTML dynamically:

```
        <label id="value_lable">


            {% for suggestion in suggestions_list %}
                {{ suggestion }}
            {% endfor %}

        </label>
```

But variable in Jinja doesn't update dynamically and print empty list.

How to print suggestions from list dynamically in HTML?

Comment: in JavaScript your `success:` function is empty so you do nothing with data from Flask.

Comment: What i need to fix?

Comment: I think you don't know how AJAX/JavaScript work. JavaScript sends data to Flask, Flask sends back some data - better as JSON - and JavaScript receives this data and updates HTML in browser.

Comment: Can you send few examples of, how a can handling this?

Comment: I `success` function you have to find element in HTML - using `$(...)` - and then you can update it - using data which you have in `response`.

Comment: I would use in Flask separated function to send sugestions.

Comment: Update inside tis success: function(response) {...} ? How i can receive data (list of suggestions) from python app?

Comment: `success: function(response)` has sugestions in variable `response`

Comment: if I try your google link directly in browser then it gives me empty page. I expect it returns data as JSON so your JavaScript could receive it directly - without Flask - and use to generate HTML on page.

Comment: XML file, not JSON

Comment: It reaturns empty file - maybe it need Google Account and Google Project with private API key.

Comment: OK, I had to use different text in query to get suggestions :)

Comment: Get data from this file - not problem (on server side via flask), problem is - dynamically print suggestions in HTML (after entering each letter in input field)

Comment: Flask should send only minimal HTML with sugestions and `sucess` should use ie. `$("#place_for_sugestions").html(response)`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Working example:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/suggestions')
def suggestions():
    text = request.args.get('jsdata')

    suggestions_list = []

    if text:
        r = requests.get('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ru&q={}&gl=in'.format(text))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        suggestions = soup.find_all('suggestion')

        for suggestion in suggestions:
            suggestions_list.append(suggestion.attrs['data'])

        #print(suggestions_list)

    return render_template('suggestions.html', suggestions=suggestions_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Suggestions</title>
</head>

<body>

Search: <input type="text" id="search_form_input"></input>

<div id="place_for_suggestions"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#search_form_input").keyup(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/suggestions",
      type: "get",
      data: {jsdata: text},
      success: function(response) {
        $("#place_for_suggestions").html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

suggestions.html

```
<label id="value_lable">
    {% for suggestion in suggestions %}
        {{ suggestion }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</label>
```

Comment: Is this considered safe? Someone could just navigate to https://.../suggestions and it would return a page. Is there some way that we can prevent returning the rendered template unless the call comes from the AJAX request?

Comment: you can check `if request.is_xhr:` to see if it was AJAX - but someone can use other tools (ie. Python module `requests`) to send request with header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`  and `is_xhr` will return `True`. You could check other headers - ie. `User-Agent` - to recognize if it is browser but other tools can also send correct header `User-Agent`. Question is if you really need so "safe" version.