# Can I use Python/Flask to compare 2 inputs in HTML?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

Im coding the following form in HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email"></input>
  <input type="email" name="email_conf"></input>
  <input type="submit" value = "Entrar"></input>
</form>
```

As Im using Flask, I would retrive the form data using `request.form('email')` and `request.form('email_conf')` and compare the content returned by the function.

But I would like to know if I could use Python in the .html file to compare the inputs by doing something like

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email"></input>
  <input type="email" name="email_conf"></input>
  {% if email == email_conf %}
    <input type="submit" value = "Entrar"></input>
  {% endif %}

</form>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Basically you want to make the comparison Before the User hits the submit buttom or Before?

Comment: Thats true, my mistake. The data is going to be be stored after the submit buttom is clicked. Can I make the comparison after the click?
Thanks for your response!

Comment: It would be best to just use javascript to make the comparison, if you want this to be done on the client side.

Comment: @leoperessoli, I mean, it seems like you've done it yourself in your own example. This:  `{% if email == email_conf %}`  is excalty what you are asking, comparing the 2 value with Python 's Jinja (Without JavaScritp=

Comment: If this don't work for you then you should specify better what you expect and why ` {% if email == email_conf %}`don't works as expected

Comment: @AbeMalla thanks for your response! I know it would be easir using js but this must be done just with Flask and HTML.

Comment: @FedericoBaù I think the comparison isn't working because the variables email and email_conf are empty. I took the if statement out of the form tag and tried to show the variables values: `{% if email == email_conf %}
 <p>{{email}}</p>
{% endif %}` however even when the emails are the same nothing is showed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before be able to make what you want do which is to "Compare 2 HTML Forms" you should do the following:

1. Make sure that you want to run the comparison (or display any other thing really) **After** the user clicked the submit button. Because if is before then this can be done with JavaScript only, but if is **after** the submit button then go to step 2.
2. You need to 'save' the state of the form From Flask's server back to the browser (Server Side ---> Client Side). I prepare a simple App in order to show you this:

### 1. Add this to app.py

```
from flask import Flask,request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('here')
        email_1 = request.form['email']
        email_2 = request.form['email_conf']
        return render_template('index.html', email_1=email_1, email_2=email_2)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### 2. Add this to template/index.html

**NOTE: You had the closing tag in the input, is not needed as input are auto closing tags**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="email" name="email">
      <input type="email" name="email_conf">

      <input type="submit" value = "Entrar">

    </form>
    <!--  Show the Output  -->
    {{email_1}} {{email_2}}

    <!--  Do wathever you want with that  -->
    {% if email_1 and email_2 %}
        {% if email_1 == email_2 %}
             <p>My email is {{email_1}} and I put the same as {{email_2}}</p>
        {% elif email_1 == 'eggs@spam.com'%}
            <p>{{email_1}} likes Python</p>
             {% for word in email_1 %}
                <option >{{word}}</option>
             {% endfor%}
        {% else %}
            <p>Something wrong with {{email_1}} maybe not match this-> {{email_2}}??</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

### Documentation

- [Add dynamic components to your HTML templates using s, Flask, and Jinja](https://medium.com/@mikaelagurney/add-dynamic-components-to-your-html-templates-using-form-s-flask-and-jinja-59b4169ec3e1)
- [Jinja 2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)
- [Flask Dynamic data update without reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40964086/13903942)
- [Flask Dynamic data update without reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963401/flask-dynamic-data-update-without-reload-page/40964086)